# Is there a way to use unbind() then bind() with a timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, bind, unbind

I want to use unbind() on all links if a condition is true and then have the links bound again after 1.5 seconds. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
   if ( /*some condition*/) {
     $('a').unbind();
     setTimeout(function(){
     $('a').bind();
     }, 1500);
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this because `.unbind()` removes the event handlers, period. All information about them is lost. You cannot ever get them back unless you had already kept a separate copy somewhere.

What you *can* do is write the handlers in such a way that they modify their behavior based on an external condition. You can then toggle this condition, making it appear as if the handlers were not bound at all.

Example (to illustrate *only*; do not use globals please!):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if (window.doNothing) {
        return;
    }
    // do something
});

if ( /*some condition*/) {
    window.doNothing = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.doNothing = false;
    }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `bind` a specific function.